Issue with PDDL Code: FF Planner Not Generating Expected Plan
I am trying to solve a planning problem in PDDL using the FF planner. I have defined a domain and a problem, but the results I am getting do not match what I expected based on ChatGPT's explanation. Below is the code and the expected results.
Domain (mover-domainP.pddl):
(define (domain mover-domainP)
  (:requirements :strips :typing :fluents :equality :conditional-effects :negative-preconditions)
  (:types 
    mover
    cell
  )
  (:functions
    (demand ?cell - cell) - number
  )

  (:predicates
    (link ?from_cell ?to_cell)
    (mover_at ?mover ?cell)
    (loaded_at ?mover ?cell)
    (loaded ?mover)
  )

  (:action load
    :parameters (?mover - mover ?from_cell - cell)
    :precondition
      (and
        (mover_at ?mover ?from_cell)
        (> (demand ?from_cell) 0)
        (not (loaded ?mover))
      )
    :effect
      (and
        (loaded ?mover)
        (loaded_at ?mover ?from_cell)
        (decrease (demand ?from_cell) 1)
      )
  )
     
  (:action haul
    :parameters (?mover - mover ?from_cell - cell ?to_cell - cell)
    :precondition
      (and
        (loaded ?mover)
        (mover_at ?mover ?from_cell)
        (link ?from_cell ?to_cell)
      )
    :effect
      (and
        (not (mover_at ?mover ?from_cell))
        (mover_at ?mover ?to_cell)
      )
  )

  (:action dump
    :parameters (?mover - mover ?dump_cell - cell)
    :precondition
      (and
        (loaded ?mover)
        (mover_at ?mover ?dump_cell)
      )
    :effect
      (and
        (not (loaded ?mover))
        (not (loaded_at ?mover ?dump_cell))
        (increase (demand ?dump_cell) 1)
      )
  )

  (:action move
    :parameters (?mover - mover ?from_cell - cell ?to_cell - cell)
    :precondition
      (and
        (not (loaded ?mover))
        (mover_at ?mover ?from_cell)
        (link ?from_cell ?to_cell)
      )
    :effect
      (and
        (mover_at ?mover ?to_cell)
        (not (mover_at ?mover ?from_cell))
      )
  )
)

and the problem file
(define (problem mover-single)
  (:domain mover-domainP)
  (:objects
    mover1 - mover
    cell1 cell2 cell3 - cell
  )
  (:init
    (= (demand cell1) -1)
    (= (demand cell2) 0)
    (= (demand cell3) 1)
    (link cell2 cell1)
    (link cell2 cell3)
    (link cell3 cell2)
    (mover_at mover1 cell3)
  )
  (:goal
    (and
      (= (demand cell1) 0)
      (= (demand cell2) 0)
      (= (demand cell3) 0)
      (mover_at mover1 cell1)
    )
  )
)

Expected Result:
According to ChatGPT, the expected plan is:
1: (haul mover1 cell3 cell2)
2: (haul mover1 cell2 cell1)
3: (dump mover1 cell1)

Result Obtained with FF:
When I run the FF planner, I get the following plan:
Plan found:
0.00000: (MOVE MOVER1 CELL3 CELL2)
0.00100: (MOVE MOVER1 CELL2 CELL1)
Identified Problem:
It seems that the FF planner is not using the load, haul, and dump actions as expected. Instead, it is only generating simple movements between the cells.
Question:
Could someone help me identify why the FF planner is not generating the expected plan? Is there an issue with the domain or problem definition that is causing this behavior? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

I did not look too deep into your PDDL, but it seems to include numeric fluents and FF is a classical planner, you might need the metric-FF or another numeric planner (assuming that your PDDL is correct).

you are correct; my PDDL includes numeric fluents, and FF is a classical planner. I have now switched to Optic (https://planning.wiki/ref/planners/optic), which supports numeric planning.
However, I'm encountering this error: "Due to type errors in the supplied domain file, the planner has to terminate. The log of type checking is as follows:
Type-checking load
mover has bad type definition."
I haven't tested on Metric-FF due to installation issues.
Any insights or suggestions are appreciated.

OPTIC is a temporal planner. I am not sure whether the numeric support in it intended for non-temporal numeric planning tasks. I would recommend trying the metric FF planner https://fai.cs.uni-saarland.de/hoffmann/metric-ff.html
